# Laravel 5.6 project does not open on Laravel 10

Tags: laravel

I have migrated a laravel 5.6 project from my friends pc and when i write a command php artisan serve it returns an error as shown on the attached image. what should be the reason for this error?

```
PS D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce> php artisan serve
PHP Warning:  require(D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

Warning: require(D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php:66
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(56): composerRequire444c8f1f8d742ab877cec02cbb1b7feb('0e6d7bf4a5811bf...', 'D:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit444c8f1f8d742ab877cec02cbb1b7feb::getLoader()
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\artisan(18): require('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php:66
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(56): composerRequire444c8f1f8d742ab877cec02cbb1b7feb('0e6d7bf4a5811bf...', 'D:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit444c8f1f8d742ab877cec02cbb1b7feb::getLoader()
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\artisan(18): require('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
PS D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce>
```

I'm quite new to laravel coding world. Hence I end up being confused.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... migrated how? you can't just take a 5.6 project and put it into the skeleton of a laravel 10 app and expect it to work

Comment: See [this info](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/releases#php-8) plus other related information at that page.

Comment: What do you mean laravel 5.6 open to laravel 10? Do you mean update version? Or open laravel 5.6 on the same xampp where you hosted your laravel 10? If you want to update version, then you would need to do this one version at a time while changing PHP version to the appropriate laravel version. If you wish to open laravel 5.6 in xampp where you host your laravel 10, then it wont work since PHP version is not compatible.